# After clearing cookies, the first product added to cart also adds a previous ordered product

Tags: php, debugging, upgrade, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have a really bizarre problem.

After updating Prestashop to the latest version (1.5.6.2), if I clear my browser cache and cookies, go to [my site](http://petiteannee.com/) and add a product to the cart it also adds another product from a previous cart. My products have custom text fields, so I can see this other product added is from a previous cart as there is someone else's personalized text. If I delete this mistakenly added product though, and add further products, I don't get this issue. It only happens after clearing the browser cache and cookies.

Where can I start to try and find the cause of this? The prestashop site and forums prove no help and never get an answer there.